# Add contents of 1 file to the top of another file without overwrite in PHP?

Tags: php

i stuck on here . i have function which rename the my text files when first one is amended.

```php
function copyFiles(string $newLine) : void
{

    rename( "file4.txt", "file5.txt");    
    rename( "file3.txt", "file4.txt");    
    rename("file2.txt", "file3.txt");
    rename("file1.txt", "file2.txt");

file_put_contents("file1.txt",$newLine."\n", FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX);
}
```

and i need to take content from the last `file5.txt`
and put it in another text file named `fullnews.txt`

if the content in `fullnews.txt` is `Hello World` and in `file5.txt` is `Good afternoon World`

after when i amend the first file i need `fullnews.txt` to look like

```
Good afternoon World
Hello World
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to go about this for such small strings is to read and store the contents of the file5.txt, and then append the read content to fullnews.txt.

```php
$content = file_get_contents("file5.txt");
file_put_contents("fullnews.txt", $content, FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: String were just for example , they will be html codes in this text file , can i use the same code?

Comment: You might have to cast the html code to a string for this logic to work. I am not terribly experienced with php, but I really don't see a reason why it wouldn't work!